# Httpclient dependency error Android Studio-Gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I'm facing HttpClient dependency issue with Gradle 1.3.0 and Android Studio 1.3.2.

With the below gradle file, The following packages which are a part of Httpclient library are not being resolved

```
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
```

Gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "xxx.xxx.xxxx"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile ('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.+') {
        exclude module: 'httpclient'
    }
   compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.2.2'
}
```

The httpclient-4.2.2.jar has to be moved to the libs directory for the dependencies to be resolved, inspite of explicitly mentioned in gradle file.

Appreciate any help..

Comment: The issue is not with Gradle 1.3.0 and Android Studio 1.3.2.
It depends by API23.

Comment: Seriously!!!! Down vote!!! I'm really getting fed up with mob justice and sheer arrogance of some of the members.. The question was upto the point and valid.

Comment: i used this tutorial http://www.blazin.in/2016/03/http-connection-for-android-marshmallow.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the docs on [behavior changes in Android M](https://developer.android.com/preview/behavior-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client).
Based on the docs you need to specify

```
android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

in your gradle script to use Apache HttpClient if you compile with API 23.

Comment: if you compile with API 23 (not target)

Comment: i used this tutorial http://www.blazin.in/2016/03/http-connection-for-android-marshmallow.html

Answer (score 0):

I think the httpclient library doesn't include the mime parts, those are in httpmime. This is a transitive dependency of httpclient,

Try adding this dependency:

```
compile "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.2.3"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this line in gradle:

```
compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
```